# Unable to convert & assign character value to a numeric field

Tags: r

I have been struggling with the following issue:

I have the following variables:

```
class(HARdata)
[1] "data.frame"
dim(HARdata)
[1] 10299    88

class(activity_labels)
[1] "character"
length(activity_labels)
[1] 6
```

I have been trying to run the following loop:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(HARdata)) { 
  for (j in 1:length(activity_labels)){
    if (as.numeric(HARdata[i, "traintype"]) == extract_numeric(activity_labels[j])) {
      HARdata[i, "traintype"] <- activity_labels[j]
    }
  }
}
```

However, i get the following error:

```
Error in if (as.numeric(HARdata[i, "traintype"]) == extract_numeric(activity_labels[j])) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

In addition: Warning message:
    NAs introduced by coercion

If I replace `HARdata[i, "traintype"] <- activity_labels[j] with HARdata[i, "traintype"] <- 10` , the code runs fine. So I suppose the problem is in this line. The left side is numeric while the right side is supposed to be character. I tried running `as.character(HARdata[i, "traintype"]) <- "test"` but this doesn't work. Can anyone see what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
test <- scan()
0.27513126 0.39694439
0.54228045 0.82751195
0.18600784 0.96602747
0.55259276 0.52368149
0.28976503 0.74500213
0.17534195 0.04931733
0.08077429 0.82169260
0.72602526 0.94921645
0.65077605 0.06989442
0.81399236 0.1379080

test <- as.data.frame(matrix(test, ncol=2))
names(test) <- c('cartype', 'traintype')

library(tidyr)

activity_labels <- c("$0.08077429", "$0.65077605")
test[,"traintype"][match(extract_numeric(activity_labels), test[,"traintype"])] <- activity_labels
```

Comment: I finally found where the error was (actually couple errors).